# Wrong pathnames with latexdiff -- flatten and multiple files added with \input

Tags: input, latexdiff

I've written my thesis in latex and have one folder per chapter and in each chapter folders, I've subfiles per sections. Now, I'm using `latexdiff` on my mac's terminal to look at difference between the original version and the revised version.

I understood that using `--flatten` allows to also check the content of files added through `\input` (or \include). However, the problem I've is that the file path is wrongly computed.

Let's take an example. In my introduction folder, I've a `intro_structure.tex` file containing the following code. These subfiles are stored, like the `intro_structure.tex` in the same introduction folder.

```
\input{introduction/introduction}
\input{introduction/intro-transition}
etc.
```

I then run the following in the terminal.

```
latexdiff --flatten firstsubmission/introduction/intro_structure.tex secondsubmission/introduction/intro_structure.tex > intro_diff.tex
```

I then get the following warning for each \input line of code.

```
WARNING: Could not find included file .../firstsubmission/introduction/introduction/introduction.tex. I will continue but not expand |\input{introduction/introduction}|
```

The issue is because they repeat twice the introduction folder in the pathname. How can I solve it?

note: I'm not that experienced in working with the terminal